# Hangfire Dispatcher stopped due to an exception - Azure Cloud MVC website

Tags: hangfire

We get these Hangfire error messages about 2 or 3 times a day at random times, even at night when there is no activity happening. These messages come at different times; they seem to be independent.

> Execution Worker is in the Failed state now due to an exception,
> execution will be retried no more than in 00:00:04
>
> Dispatcher is stopped due to an exception, you need to restart the
> server manually. Please report it to Hangfire developers.

We have Hangfire running in a website hosted in the Azure Cloud, and we have the “Always On” setting turned on.

It is an ASP.NET 4.61 MVC website.

Here is our configuration in Global.asax.cs:

```
HangfireAspNet.Use(GetHangfireServers);
.
.
.
private IEnumerable GetHangfireServers()
{
Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
.UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
.UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
.UseNinjectActivator(_kernel)
.UseNLogLogProvider()
.UseSqlServerStorage(“SQL connection string”, new SqlServerStorageOptions
{
 CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
 SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
 QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
 UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
 DisableGlobalLocks = true
});

yield return new BackgroundJobServer();
}
```

We have this in the Owin Startup.cs file:

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
 Authorization = Enumerable.Empty()
});
```

We have these packages installed:

- Hangfire.AspNet version=0.2.0
- Hangfire.Core version=1.7.28
- Hangfire.Ninject version=1.2.0
- Hangfire.SqlServer version=1.7.28

Our website (hosted in the Azure Cloud) has 5 webservers that are load-balanced, so we normally have 5 Hangfire servers running.

Does anyone have ideas on how we can solve this? Or any ideas on how we can troubleshoot this?

Thank You

**Update**

Here is the inner exception for the "Execution Worker" error.

Execution Worker is in the Failed state now due to an exception, execution will be retried no more than in 00:00:04 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Login failed for user '...'. Token is expired.
A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

Any ideas on how we can refresh the Token?  Maybe it expires if there is no activity?  So maybe we need to have a scheduled job that will refresh the token?

The "Dispatcher Error" stopped happening.  I think it may be related to the "ghost servers" that @jbl mentioned below.  I'm not sure, but I think we got ghost servers during the deployment process.  We deploy new code to a "deployment slot", and then the deployment slot swaps into the production slot.  Somewhere in the deployment process some hangfire servers were not shutdown properly and they became ghost servers (that's my guess).  What seemed to solve the issue is that we restart both slots after a deployment to make sure all the hangfire servers are shutdown.

Thank You

Comment: Not really helpful in your case, but an example of what may cause this kind of issue https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1949
In our case, the faulting server stayed as a "ghost server". It was still sending healthchecks, but it did not appear in the hangfire servers list and was not processing any new job.
We "solved" the issue by adding a hangfire process running every five minutes and redeclaring the server if it detects it as "ghost" (sending healthchecks but not apperaing in the servers list)

Comment: Thanks for the details. Actually, the reason is hidden inside the inner exception, e.g. original exception that caused this message. Logging frameworks allow to log inner exceptions, and usually googling like "nlog inner exception" where "nlog" is the name of your framework reveals how to do this. Could you include the inner exception as well?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments and thanks for the tips!  I googled on how to log inner exceptions, however it seems like the problem is not happening as often now.   If the problem happens again, hopefully I will get the inner exception this time.

Comment: Here is the inner exception for the Execution Worker error:  Execution Worker is in the Failed state now due to an exception, execution will be retried no more than in 00:00:04 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Login failed for user '...'. Token is expired. A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.